# PHP loop from database and calculate

Tags: php

```
$st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=? ORDER BY id ASC");
            $st->execute(array($id));

            if($st->rowCount() >= 1){
                foreach ($st as $row) { 
                    echo $row["exp"]."+";
                }
            }
```

So what I've tried is to echo `$row["exp"]."+";` to simply add in a loop, but it just print it out. How can I fix?

Comment: Why not simply edit your query `SELECT SUM(exp) as exp ...`

Comment: _"to simply add in a loop, but it just print it out."_ Because it's incorrect syntax for addition? - You are telling php to echo a string, and that string is a +

Comment: @Epodax Technically the string would be the value of `$row['exp']` plus the `+` sign.

Comment: to add, $sum=0; foreach(){$row["exp"] = $row["exp"]+$sum;} and than echo outside the loop. but

Comment: Plus you are not fetching data from your query result!!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
  $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=? ORDER BY id ASC");
        $st->execute(array($id));
        $sum=0;
        if($st->rowCount() >= 1){

            foreach ($st as $row) { 
                $sum += $row["exp"];
            }
            echo $sum
        }
```

you can also get sum of exp by single query SELECT SUM(exp) as exp FROM users WHERE id=? ORDER BY id ASC

Answer (score 0):

Here, this should give you all the answers you need: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php.html

In particular, look at section 6, [Addition in PHP](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php2p6.html)